# How to set path for GraphVIZ executable using UWSGI with a Python virtual environment on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, uwsgi, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am running a Flask app over UWSGI and nginx. In my Flask app, I use GraphVIZ.

If I run Flask directly, everything works. However, if I run it through UWSGI, I get the following fatal error:
    graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg', '-O', 'graphviz_dot_graph'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

I have checked that my GraphVIZ installation is on /usr/bin, and $PATH does include /usr/bin. It seems that either UWSGI (or perhaps nginx) overrides my system path so a script that is easily found when run directly is not found anymore.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Please paste some code. How do you invoke the graphviz command?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this, it seems that invoking the virtual environment overrides my path. The solution to this was adding the following workaround to the Flask Python script:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'/usr/bin'
```

Replace the /usr/bin to wherever your GraphVIZ executable is (which you can normally deduce by writing 'whereis graphviz' on your shell).